# Java Shared (crossed) Dependency Management

Tags: java, gradle

Lets say I am building a java application that relies on a two libraries: A and B. Both A and B are dependent on on a library C. What is the best way to manage that A and B are using the same version so they don't conflict? I am using Gradle.

Comment: @Makoto I am using Gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Gradle 4.6 (5.x) [Gradle provides support](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html#sec:bom_import) for importing [bill of materials (BOM) files](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies), which are effectively `.pom` files that use `<dependencyManagement>` to control the dependency versions of direct and transitive dependencies. Sounds like what you need. So, if library C has a BOM just import that BOM of the version you want to enforce:

```
dependencies {
    // import a BOM
    implementation(enforcedPlatform("com.acme:c-bom:1.0.0"))

    implementation("com.acme:a:1.2.3")
    implementation("com.acme:b:4.5.6")
}
```

If the library does not have a BOM, just declare it explicitly:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("com.acme:c:1.0.0")

    implementation("com.acme:a:1.2.3")
    implementation("com.acme:b:4.5.6")
}
```